# Absolute positioned div inside another absolute positioned div is not stretching by content

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have two div elements with "position: absolute" css rule set. Inside the child div there are two floated div elements. The weird part is that the child div is not stretching properly with the content. It is wrapping everything inside on new line. It behaves like the child div is inheriting the width from parent div and is streched only the minimum it needs to display the content. If I remove the parent div or set the sufficient width, the child div is stretched properly. What css rule or specification is constraining the child div to not stretch? Thanks for your replies.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="textbox">
      <div class="alignleft">Text on the left.</div>
      <div class="alignright">Text on the right.</div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rnwmxaLh/2/

Answer (score 0):

The `absolute position` on `#textbox` is the culprit here.
Remove that, and the div will stretch.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

#textbox {
  /****position: absolute;****/
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="textbox">
    <div class="alignleft">Text on the left.</div>
    <div class="alignright">Text on the right.</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I should be more specific. I can not change the position attributes because it is more complicated in real than in this example. However i can play around with other css rules and the content of these div's. And I want to find out what rule is causing these behavior.